# Error when comparing hashes when logging in

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, encryption, sha

i'm creating a simple login system, i has the passwords using sha256 and store a salt using a random number in the database. However when i try to log in, when it goes to compare the hashes it fails. Can anyone see why?

```
   <?php
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$mysql_db_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_db_user = "root";
$mysql_db_database = "login";

$con = mysql_connect($mysql_db_hostname, $mysql_db_user) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_db_database, $con) or die("Could not select database");

$query = "SELECT password, salt FROM registered_users WHERE username='$username'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) //no such user exists
{

            echo 'false';
            header('Location: index.php');
}
$userData = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password) );
if($hash != $userData['password']) //incorrect password
{   

            echo 'false';
            header('Location: index.php');

}
else
{
    echo 'true';
     $_SESSION['username']=$row['username'];    

}
session_write_close();
```

Heres how i hash my pass

```
// hash the password using sha256 a string of 64 characters
$hash = hash('sha256', $password);
// create the salt, random string of characters appened to hash
function createSalt()
{
    $string = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    return substr($string, 0, 3);
}
$salt = createSalt();
$hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);
```

Heres how i insert my data

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO registered_users(username, name, email, password,salt)VALUES('$username', '$name', '$email', '$hash', '$salt')");
header("location: index.php?remarks-success");
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: can you write error ?

Comment: It just can't find the password i think

Comment: Plus, make sure that the same storage method was used. Try using `mysql_fetch_row` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`

Comment: `$password` is a stray variable; is that coming from user input? Please post full code.

Comment: How is the data initially inserted? You haven't posted that.

Comment: i have updated it again

Comment: Ok. I tested your code and it checked out for me. I think it may be your sessions that are playing tricks on you. However, I don't see a `$salt` variable such as `$salt = "somesaltedtext";` for your password creation method, which is something I added and it worked.

Comment: I do $salt = createSalt();

Comment: How could i fix the sessions

Comment: Not defining `$salt` will end up with a blank entry in the `salt` column, which is what happened when I tested it now.

Comment: I get a salt number, i checked in my database

Comment: Could you possibly some me the structure of your database?

Comment: Wait, scratch that. I figured out what the problem is.

Comment: You're welcome. Consult my answer below. @NickPocock

Comment: My answer has been deleted. Seems like there's no pleasing you. Figure it out for yourself; I spent over an hour with you. I should be sending you an invoice for all this.

Comment: I'm not sure why it has been deleted? I went to bed and was going to accept the answer in the morning. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are storing the password in the database the same way you are checking it here.

So to put it in you should create the hash by first hashing the password, then rehashing it with a salt. If they don't match, then there is your problem.

Comment: This is how i create my pass

$hash = hash('sha256', $password);
// create the salt, random string of characters appened to hash
function createSalt()
{
    $string = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    return substr($string, 0, 3);
}
$salt = createSalt();
$hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);